# Search in a xml gridview.

Tags: asp.net, xml, search, gridview, xmlnode

This is my first question here at Stack Overflow and i will be as precise as possible.

I am working on an ASP.NET Web application and i have a gridview which have a XML as a datasource. I already have it bound as a datasource and it works perfect.

I have a textbox and a button in my project and want to search in the gridview.

Here is an example of one of the nodes in the XML file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvVeL.png

The problem I currently have is that I am stuck at the search gridview part.

I have as I said before a textbox and a button and when i write a value in the textbox and press on the button i want to search the gridview and its nodes to check if for an example any titles contains the words from the textbox.

Right now I have the corresponding code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgU2T.png

This code is in the buttonSearch Click event. The SearchBookBox.text is the Text i want to search for in the Gridview.

I am stuck right now and i need some help.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("/NewFolder1/books.xml"));

GridView1.DataSource = ds;

GridView1.DataBind();
```

The above code is the code which i bind the gridview to the corresponding xml file. This code is in my Page_Load Event.

I have tried different ideas to solve this issue, but nothing works.

Right now the code is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace BookSearch
{
    public partial class BookSearchForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Visible = false;
            AddBooksXML();

        }

        private void AddBooksXML()
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("/NewFolder1/books.xml"));
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void BookSearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(SearchBookBox.Text != null)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode node in ds.GetXml)
                {
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("ERROR!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really need some help. As i said, i have tried different ideas, but I am stuck and I can't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a possible solution.

```
protected void XmlSearch(string searchText)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("/NewFolder1/books.xml"));
    var dat = from books in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
       where books.Field<string>("author") == searchText || book.Field<string>("title") == searchText
       select books;

    GridView1.DataSource = dat.CopyToDataTable();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

This will search in author and title for exact matches its probably not the best solution but its a example of how you could do it.

Requires

```
using System.Linq;
```

**EDIT**

If you wanna loop through them you can use

```
foreach (var book in dat)
{
   var bookInfo = String.Format("{0} {1}", book["author"].ToString(), book["title"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: I have found another solution on a blog site. 

http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/10/bind-search-xml-file-data-and-display.html

This is what i wanted and the above pages solution worked perfectly. It uses Linq and I got the result exactly what i needed. 

This issue has been solved!